# Save listview item back to listview from another activity

Tags: android, listview

I have two activities: **Main** and **Editing**. When i click on an item in listview, it **takes me to the editing activity** where it shows that items details (Name, surname, cell and email) in their respective textviews. When i click the edit button, the textviews become editable and when i click the save button, i need the listview in the main activity to be updated. Please provide code as i am still a beginner.

**Code for my main class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Button btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
ListView lstInfo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstInfo);
Button btnName = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnName);
Button btnSurname = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSurname

);
    Button btnEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEmail);
    Button btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

    final List<Contact> items = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Select a contact to delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get views
//        Button btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
//        ListView lstInfo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstInfo);
//        Button btnName = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnName);
//        Button btnSurname = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSurname);
//        Button btnEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEmail);
//        Button btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
//
//        final List<Contact> items = new ArrayList<Contact>();

        //Hard-coding contacts
        items.add(new Contact("Sally", "Van Der Walt", "0766838275", "sally@gmail.com"));
        items.add(new Contact("Sarah", "Smith", "0847852693", "sarah@gmail.com"));
        items.add(new Contact("John", "Doe", "0823691478", "john@gmail.com"));


        // create adapter to transform string items
        final ContactAdapter adapter = new ContactAdapter(this, items);
        //final ContactAdapter conAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this, items);

        // attach adapter to list view
        lstInfo.setAdapter(adapter);

        // add more items when clicked
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.add(new Contact("Name", "Surname", "Cell", "Email"));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "New contact has been added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //Delete the selected user - the selected user will appear in green
        lstInfo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (list.size() >= 1)
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        if (position == list.get(i))
                            return;
                    }
                Contact cur = items.get(position);
                list.add(position);
                cur.setSelected("(Selected)");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });


        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    items.remove(list.get(i).intValue());

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                list.clear();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Contact has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //
//        btnDelete.setOnItemClickListener(new Adapter.OnItemClickListener() {
//            @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, android.view.View view, int position, long id) {
//                list.remove(position);
//            }
//        });


        //
        //Sorting using the adapters sort method
        btnName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.sort(new Comparator<Contact>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Contact left, Contact right) {
                        return left.firstName.compareTo(right.firstName);
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        btnSurname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.sort(new Comparator<Contact>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Contact left, Contact right) {
                        return left.surname.compareTo(right.surname);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        btnEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.sort(new Comparator<Contact>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Contact left, Contact right) {
                        return left.email.compareTo(right.email);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

             lstInfo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String nameItem = items.get(position).getFirstName();
                String surnameItem = items.get(position).getSurname();
                String cellItem = items.get(position).getCellNumber();
                String emailItem = items.get(position).getEmail();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditingActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("name", nameItem);
                intent.putExtra("surname", surnameItem);
                intent.putExtra("cell", cellItem);
                intent.putExtra("email", emailItem);

                //startActivity(intent);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
            }
        });
    }

**Code for my editing class:**
    public class EditingActivity extends Activity {

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.setContentView(R.layout.edit_contact);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            if (intent != null)
            {
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                if (extras != null)
                {
                    //Get the bundled values
                    String name = extras.getString("name");
                    String surname = extras.getString("surname");
                    String cell = extras.getString("cell");
                    String email = extras.getString("email");

                    //Display the values
                    TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
                    TextView txtSurname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.surnameTV);
                    TextView txtCell = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cellTV);
                    TextView txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailTV);

                    txtName.setText(name);
                    txtSurname.setText(surname);
                    txtCell.setText(cell);
                    txtEmail.setText(email);


                }
            }

            Button editBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editBtn);

            editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
                    TextView txtSurname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.surnameTV);
                    TextView txtCell = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cellTV);
                    TextView txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailTV);

                    txtName.setEnabled(true);
                    txtSurname.setEnabled(true);
                    txtCell.setEnabled(true);
                    txtEmail.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });

            Button saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);

            saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Post what you done so far

Comment: I added it above :)

Comment: Can you post the mainActivity code? How did you update values to the list view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `startActivityForResult()` check the below code for reference -

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);  
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with requestCode 2  
            }  
        });  
    }  
 // Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity  
    @Override  
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
       {  
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
                  // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
                   if(requestCode==2)  
                         {  
                            String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
                            textView1.setText(message);  
                         }  
     }
```

`onActivityResult` can be used to check for any updates to the edited data.

Inside the Editing Class you will have to do this -

```
@Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);  
        editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
            button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
                @Override  
                public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                    String message=editText1.getText().toString();  
                    Intent intent=new Intent();  
                    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  
                    setResult(2,intent);  
                    finish();//finishing activity  
                }  
            });  
    }
```

For further understanding `startActivityForResult()` you can refer this [Java Point Link](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example).

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Thank you so so much! Both of those methods go in the Main class and not the Editing class?

Comment: Yes. They both go inside the Main Class, I've updated the answer, check what you need to do inside the Editing Class.

Comment: You've been amazing thank you! In my Main activity under onActivityResult method, how would I add it to my listview if im using a custom adapater? My adapter has four textviews (name, surname, cell and email) so i cant do this: textView1.setText(message); ?

Comment: If you are passing the values through an ArrayList to your adapter, you can add the data to the ArrayList and set the adapter in the onActivityResult() method. Also do accept the answer by clicking on the tick, if it has helped you. :)

Comment: Ive added all my code for my Main class above if that'll help. Can you please give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Just do this inside the `onActivityResult()` - `adapter.add(new Contact("UpdatedName", "UpdatedSurname", "UpdatedCell", "UpdatedEmail"));` this updatedValues are the ones that you get in the `Bundle` and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` Let me know if this works.

Comment: Your work is wonderful thank you! Do you know how to delete an item from the listview from the Editing activity? When I press a certain contact in the listview, it will take me to its details where I can edit them. Theres a button at the bottom of that screen where if i push it, an alert dialog must pop up and ask if i want to delete the contact and if i say yes, it gets deleted from the listview. Hope i made sense :)

Comment: You just have to delete it from the ArrayList, refer this for more info about it - [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372301/how-do-i-delete-an-item-from-my-custom-base-adapter)

Answer (score 0):

```
lstInfo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String nameItem = items.get(position).getFirstName();
            String surnameItem = items.get(position).getSurname();
            String cellItem = items.get(position).getCellNumber();
            String emailItem = items.get(position).getEmail();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditingActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("name", nameItem);
            intent.putExtra("surname", surnameItem);
            intent.putExtra("cell", cellItem);
            intent.putExtra("email", emailItem);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

first directly pass the item object replace above code with

```
lstInfo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditingActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("ItemDetails", items.get(position));

            startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

Access Object using

```
ItemObject details= getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ItemDetails");
```

in Edit Activity modify code on save button

```
 Button saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);

        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

             Intent intent=new Intent();
              intent.putExtra("ItemDetail",updateItems);
              setResult(REQUEST_CODE,intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why should the developer getSerializableExtra()? if the data is a simple string?

Comment: i have changed items.get(position).getFirstName()  to  items.get(position) so now it's object not a string,there is no need to pass individual parameter.